# How can I add .NET framework 4.5.2 to Asp.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-4.5

If I click add reference I get

> *The following projects are not supported as references... AspNetCore version 1.0 and .NETFramework version 4.5.2*

I follow this [article](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToReferenceAnExistingNETFrameworkProjectInAnASPNETCore10WebApp.aspx) but no success.
I changed the project.json with

```
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    },
    "net452": {
      "dependencies": {
        "T4Generator": {
          "target": "project"
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

And doesn't work, my .NET framework 4.5.2 is named T4Generator.

Is possible to add this project to Core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two versions of .NET Core, .NET Standard version (Portable version, which you use in your project) and full .NET framework version.

If you choose portable version of .NET Core, then all the packages and libraries should be in .NET standard in order to use them. Unfortunately most of .NET framework packages are not ported to .NET standard yet.

Best way to solve your issue is converting your application to use full .NET Framework version of .NET Core. If not you can't use most of packages like T4Generator.

I would suggest you you to upgrade your project to use VS 2017 with csproj rather than project.json which is obsolete. Then convert.

[Convert .Net Core to .Net Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42623103/convert-net-core-to-net-framework)

Comment: full .NET framework version is something like Core with more features or is complete different and continues of 4.6 framework?

Comment: Full .NET framework does not support cross platforms, for example if you want to run your application on Mac, linux etc. That is the main difference when using full .NET frameowk. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42939454/what-is-the-difference-between-net-core-and-net-standard-class-library-project

Comment: @DSR
Quote: 'There are two versions of .NET Core....'.
as far as I understand dotnet core is not dotnet framework, however previous versions of asp.net core were able to target the full net framework.